# Understanding Joule heating

Tags: electricity, electrons, thermoelectricity

I’ve started my college classes, and I hadn’t cleared up something I wasn’t understanding.  Under the conditions of current=voltage/resistance and heat generated by current=I^2*R, what confuses me is that I think it suggests that all the electrical energy will be used up as heat.  (Because IV=I^R).  What am I missing here?  Do thermally excited electrons transfer the energy and the energy actually lost because of heat can be determined by the heat that escapes the sides of wires?

Comment: What makes you think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up a "simple" circuit: one with a voltage source and a single resistor, then yes, all the power in the circuit is consumed by the resistor, which converts it to heat.  Because that one resistor determines the current.

But consider a more complex circuit with many different resistors (and potentially other elements).  The current through the circuit depends on all of them together.

So when you look at only a single resistive element, you can't determine the current.  Changing the resistance a little bit may make almost no change in the current.  In such a case, you can still determine the heat loss *in that element* by determining the current through that element and the resistance.

You can use this in a case where $V=IR$ isn't useful.  You can't use that unless you know the entire $R$, or if you know the voltage drop across your single element.

Answer (score 4):

The heat produced in a wire by a current comes from the loss of potential energy $eV$ of the electrons when they move from the negative potential terminal (high potential energy) to the positive terminal of the resistor. $-e$ is the electron charge, $-V$ is the electrical potential difference with respect to the positive resistor terminal. This energy is converted to thermal energy (Joule's heat) of the wire by collisions of the electrons with the crystal lattice. The total energy per unit time $Q$ produced as Joule's heat is thus proportional to the number of electrons moving from the high to the low potential terminal per unit time and thus to the electric current $$Q=V I=I^2 R$$.

Comment: In many small steps of about the relaxation time $\tau = 10^{-14}$ seconds.

Comment: I’m still unclear about how much of the energy is lost to heat.

Comment: @Tom - When an electron traverses the resistor from the negative terminal to the positive terminal *all of its potential energy* $eV$ is converted into heat released in the wire in many small steps. This happens for each electron that participates in  the flow of the huge number of electrons producing the current flow through the resistor.